# Bug with jquery .on and facebox

Tags: jquery, facebox, jquery-on

I have an element that loads from AJAX. With tthat element, I attached Facebox.js. When the element is clicked, it will triggered Facebox. So I used:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[rel*=modal]", function() {
    $(this).facebox(); // Applies modal window to any link with attribute rel="modal"
});
```

The thing is, it requires the element to be clicked twice before Facebox is triggered. So as a quick fix, I added:

```
$('a[rel*=modal]').trigger('click');
```

This way, I can click the element only once to trigger. Is there a better way to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when the first click happens the `facebox` plugin is not initialized, a workaround is to initialize the plugin and then re-trigger the click event again

```
$(document).one("click", "a[rel*=modal]", function() {
    $(this).facebox().triggerHandler('click');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Arun. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I happen to encounter same issues when using Jquery on with other plugins. It looks like your answer can apply to them too.